# get the images from drawable

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am beginner in android development 
my question is how can i load this image's from drawables
to adapter using getResource function
and how to get all the items inside drawbles into the adapter class
(this is my sample data class where image is loaded to the image adapter)

```
public class SampleData {

      public static final int SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT = 20;

        static int i;

public static ArrayList<Data> generateSampleData() {
    String repeat = " repeat";

    final ArrayList<Data> datas = new ArrayList<Data>();
    for (i = 0; i < SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT; i++) {
        Data data = new Data();
        if (i == 0) {
            data.imageUrl = R.drawable.a;
        }
        if (i == 1) {
            data.imageUrl = R.drawable.b;

        }
        if (i == 2) {
            data.imageUrl = R.drawable.c;

        } else if (i == 3) {
            data.imageUrl = R.drawable.d;

        } else if (i == 4) {
            data.imageUrl = R.drawable.e;

        } else if (i == 5) {
            data.imageUrl = R.drawable.f;

        } else if (i == 6) {
            data.imageUrl = R.drawable.g;

        } else if (i == 7) {
            data.imageUrl = R.drawable.h;

        } else if (i == 8) {
            data.imageUrl = R.drawable.i;

        } else if (i == 10) {
            data.imageUrl = R.drawable.j;

        } else if (i == 11) {
            data.imageUrl = R.drawable.k;

        } else if (i == 12) {
            data.imageUrl = R.drawable.l;

        } else if (i == 13) {
            data.imageUrl = R.drawable.m;


        } else if (i == 13) {
            data.imageUrl = R.drawable.m;
        } else if (i == 13) {
            data.imageUrl = R.drawable.o;
        } else if (i == 13) {
            data.imageUrl = R.drawable.p;
        } else if (i == 13) {
            data.imageUrl = R.drawable.q;
        }

        /*data.title = "Gif Card";
        data.description = "Super awesome description";
        Random ran = new Random();
        int x = ran.nextInt(i + SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT);
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
            data.description += repeat;*/

        datas.add(data);
    }
    return datas;
}

}
```

Comment: Use a `switch` statement. It's not `more efficient`. Just `more elegant`.

Answer (score 1):

if you consider that the char `a` in the ascii table is decimal `97`, `b` is `98` and so on, what you could do is

```
public static ArrayList<Data> generateSampleData(Context context) {
   String repeat = " repeat";

   final ArrayList<Data> datas = new ArrayList<Data>();
   for (i = 0; i < SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT; i++) {
       Data data = new Data();
       data.imageUrl = context.getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf((char)(97+i)), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
       datas.add(data);
    }
    return data; 
}
```

if your drawables follow the same naming convention you won't need the switch or if construct, but just the loop. Of course you need the Context to access the resources, so I changed the signature of your method

Comment: thaks for the answer ,but iam getting a error value of string cant be applied

Comment: Error:(72, 92) error: method generateSampleData in class SampleData cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Yes, the method takes a context object as parameter

Comment: can u help me  out wat shuld i do

Comment: you should provide a context to the method. E.g. if you call it from onCreate of your Activity, you can use `this`

Answer (score 0):

If the number of drawables is equal to your SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT -

```
final ArrayList<Data> datas = new ArrayList<Data>();
final int[] drawables = {
      R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, ...          
};
for (i = 0; i < drawables.length; i++) {
    Data data = new Data();
    data.imageUrl = drawables[i];
    datas.add(data);
}
return datas;
```

This saves series of ifs / switch statements in each iteration, as well as more expensive calls to the system.